# htaccess opencart duplicate homepage variations

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, opencart

I want to make changes to my htaccess file so that if someone puts in mydomain.com/index.php or mydomain.com/index.php?route=common/home it redirects them to mydomain.com.  I have already have my domain redirecting from www.mydoamin.com to mydomain.com. Below is what I have in my file to do this. Now I don't understand this at all but I got it of a thread here and it works for me.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^vineyardwine\.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://vineyardwine.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I got the following off different threads but they don't seem to be doing anything, any help/constructive critique will be greatly appreciated.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this right below `RewriteBase /`:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+index\.php(\ |\?route=common/home|$) 
RewriteRule ^ /? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Will I leave the rest of the RewriteRules as they are or can they be deleted?

Comment: Also just adding this on, its working fine for the index.php but when I got mydomain.com/index.php?route=common/home its rediredting to mydomain.com/?route=common/home

Comment: @user3367840 You don't need to remove your other rules, just make sure this one is *before* your other rules. Also, I left out a `?` in the rule's target. See edit